# MVC-Mini-Profiler - Profile EF 4.1 over WCF service

Tags: model-view-controller, mvc-mini-profiler

I want to be a able to profile a EF 4.1 DbContext, which is not accessed direct from the website but via a WCF service.  Is it possible to profile this as well?

Thanks

Comment: see our latest wcf sample in the repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered the question in great detail here: [MvcMiniProfiler profiling web app and lower layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530027/mvcminiprofiler-profiling-web-app-and-lower-layers/7555881#7555881)

You can also view the sample's that Sam has put together here: 
http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/source/browse/