# MiniProfiler with multilayered WCF services

Tags: wcf, mvc-mini-profiler

I have a set of WCF services that call each other I would like to use the MiniProfiler to profiles the complete stack, right the way down to the MVC site that uses them.  It looks something like this:

MVC Site -> Facade WCF Service -> Capability WCF Service

I found this question [MvcMiniProfiler profiling web app and lower layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530027/mvcminiprofiler-profiling-web-app-and-lower-layers) and got it up and running.  When I tried to implement this in the Capability WCF Service below the Facade WCF Service but I don't get any profiling info back.

Does anyone has any ideas if this should work or what I have to do to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should and does work across multiple layers of WCF service.

To get this to work is actually pretty straight forward and exactly as you might expect:

1. Follow the instructions here [MvcMiniProfiler profiling web app and lower layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530027/mvcminiprofiler-profiling-web-app-and-lower-layers)
2. **Add** the **behaviourConfiguration** attribute to the **client endpoint** as well as the service endpoint in the WCF service that calls the other WCF service(s).
3. Follow the steps in **"Setup WCF Host"** from **step 1** above for the WCF service that is getting called.
4. Sit back and enjoy the profiling goodness. ;)

> It is worth downloading the code for the MiniProfiler.WCF and taking a look I had not
>   come across this technique before.
>   https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler