# profiling wcf and mvc 4 with miniprofiler

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, profiling, mvc-mini-profiler, mvcminiprofiler

I am working with miniprofiler and find it very helpful.

I have an mvc4 application that gets its data from a set of wcf services over named pipes. I am in control of both the mvc4 app and the wcf services.

I was reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530027/mvcminiprofiler-profiling-web-app-and-lower-layers)  on how to profile the lower layers of the architecture, but maybe I missing something but could not find MvcMiniProfiler.WCF package or part of the MvcMiniProfiler package. Is this still available?

Another question I have is it possible to set up miniprofiler to log to file? I have automated performance tests that are ran against my application that I would like to record the profiling for to understand how the application behaves under load.

Comment: Anyone got information on this please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MvcMiniProfiler profiling web app and lower layers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530027/mvcminiprofiler-profiling-web-app-and-lower-layers)